# Python imports not being recognised

Tags: python, import, user-defined-functions

I have been putting a collection of functions I've written into what should be a more organised format so they could be imported when required but it looks like I've not got the structure right and need some advice.

At present I have the file `UsefulFunctions.py`

At the top of the file I have collated the import statements e.g.
`import pandas as pd`

Below this I have created separate classes to hold similar functions. Each function is a static method within a class, here is an extract that will serve to explain the problem:

**UsefulFunctions.py**

```
import pandas as pd

class Pandas_functions:

    @staticmethod
    def null_values(dataframe):
        """
        Returns a dataframe of the count of null and N/A values per column of
        the input dataframe
        
        Parameters:
        -----------
        dataframe: a pandas dataframe
        
        Returns:
        --------
        A pandas dataframe listing all column features and the sum of Null & Empty
        values per feature
        """

        a = dataframe.isnull().astype(int).sum()
        b = (dataframe=="").astype(int).sum()
        result = pd.DataFrame(data=[a,b], index=['Null','Empty']).T
        
        return result
```

When I then `import UsefulFunction` in a separate notebook and try to use `UsefulFunctions.Pandas_functions.null_values(df)` I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-7c232dd49b55> in <module>
----> 1 UsefulFunctions.Pandas_functions.null_values(df_docks)

~\Synoptic Project\UsefulFunctions.py in null_values(dataframe)
    190         --------
    191         A pandas dataframe listing all column features and the sum of Null & Empty
--> 192         values per feature
    193         """
    194 

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

​
```

Clearly, pd is defined in UsefFunctions.py and I've imported it to the notebook I'm working on. So, I am unsure what I am missing here in order to get that function working.

Can anyone please advise how I ought to be doing this?

Thanks

Comment: please, post full traceback, not just the last line. Also edit your code to include the relevant imports present in your module, so that there is no confusion. You are expected to provide [mcve].

Comment: write `import pandas as pd` at the beginning of the program

Comment: Apologies @buran, this is the first question I've posted. I've edited it to show the full traceback and to make it clearer.  @Dinesh, I've already got `import pandas as pd` at the top of the UsefulFunctions.py file and the notebook I'm importing it to. I presume I must have organised my code structure incorrectly?

Comment: It's strange that traceback points to a line in the docstring and is not helpful at all. Maybe check that your actual code is not something like `import pandas as Pd`.

Comment: Thanks @buran, I've checked and it's not.  Interestingly, I moved the function outside of the class and it works! So, must be something to do with the way I've organised the code.

Comment: Using class in a case like this really does not make sense, but it should not affect the scope of `pd` imported at module level. It will be alias available trough whole module

Comment: @buran, fair enough. This is just one function example: all the functions are affected similarly. If it's not good design then I'll just remove the classes and perhaps group them in separate files

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing this statement at the beginning of your file

[image]

Comment: Sorry @Chandral, I may not have been clear enough the first time, perhaps now I've re-edited it is? I've already got `import pandas as pd` at the top of each of the UsefulFunctions.py file and the notebook I'm importing it to. So, I'm not sure what I need to do to my code structure to get this working.

Comment: This is really strange. What exactly is being passed as a parameter for `dataframe` ?

Comment: I'm passing a pandas dataframe. Funnily enough, when I take out the classes & @statickmethod they all work. I was using the classes to organise the functions, but maybe instead I should just put them in separate files. It's still an interesting problem that would be nice to solve!

Comment: The Traceback shows the NameError is occurring right after your doc string int the function `null_values` ends. It should rather occur at `result = pd.DataFrame(data=[a,b], index=['Null','Empty']).T` where you are actually using `pd` for the first time in your function.

Can you try printing `pd` before your doc string in the function? See if it prints something like this `<module 'pandas' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py'>` in the console. That way we can ensure the NameError is not happening within `UsefulFunctions.py` at least.